# How do you get the current fragment's ID?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I've created a ViewPager with 8 fragments that use the same xml layout.
However, I want different fragments to use different content.
I need to get the ID of whatever fragment it is so I can load specific content onto that fragment.

I've tried

```
extras.putInt(Globals.KEY_CATEGORY_POSITION, position);
fragment.setArguments(extras);
```

in the getItem(int position) method on the FragmentPagerAdapter.

Then, I get the position of the fragment in the Fragment class. When I do this, I go from 0 to 7 when I print out the position of each fragment but then all of them increment to 7 so they all become the same fragment.

Is there any other way to get the ID for each fragment?

Comment: you can use tag property to identify fragment in ViewPager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quite nice example:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentPagerSupport.java

When you are creating fragment:

```
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);
```

And then in fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw this inside your FragmentPagerAdapter :)

```
public Fragment getActiveFragment(ViewPager container, int position) {
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position);
    return  mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
}

private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}
```